# Table with unique constraint has duplicate records (MySQL 5.1.57)

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, duplicate-data

I recently ran into a quite puzzling situation.
In a table which **has** a unique constraint set on 2 fields, there are many existing records that violate this constraint!

And the main question is: 
**How could they have gotten there in the first place, with the unique constraint already in place?**

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `rest_service_mediafile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_encoding_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rest_service_mediafile_video_id_4a2efdd4_uniq` (`video_id`,`video_encoding_id`),
  KEY `rest_service_mediafile_5d9d774` (`video_id`),
  KEY `rest_service_mediafile_62de6709` (`video_encoding_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `video_encoding_id_refs_id_3122bd65` FOREIGN KEY (`video_encoding_id`) REFERENCES `rest_service_videoencoding` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `video_id_refs_id_567c8704` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `rest_service_video` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=93154 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample query: (but this is not the only duplicate)

```
mysql> select id, video_id, video_encoding_id, external_id from rest_service_mediafile where video_id = 157165 and video_encoding_id=2;
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
| id    | video_id | video_encoding_id | external_id |
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
| 82416 |   157165 |                 2 |           0 | 
| 82424 |   157165 |                 2 |           0 | 
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
```

And if I try an alter table query on some field like:

**ALTER TABLE `rest_service_mediafile` MODIFY `external_id` varchar(255) NULL;**

I **will** get the constraint error:
The error was: (1062, "Duplicate entry '157165-2' for key 'rest_service_mediafile_video_id_4a2efdd4_uniq'")

Also if I try to simply insert a duplicate value, it will fail correctly!
Any of you encountered a scenario in which this is possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Was the constraint added *post hoc*?

Bug:  [ALTER IGNORE TABLE t ADD UNIQUE INDEX does not delete duplicate rows](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344) in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5.

This is noted in the InnoDB docs as a [Limitation of Fast Index Creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html).

Comment: So ALTER IGNORE fails with duplicate error, does *not* delete the duplicate rows *and* it does add the unique index at the same time? By reading through the bug report, the last part doesn't seem to be the case or I've missed it? Useful reference in any case, thanks. The constraint almost surely wasn't there from the very beginning, so it's a possible scenario.